# Close Fancybox iframe on form submit using BUTTON tag - not working

Tags: jquery, forms, button, onclick, fancybox

According to the Fancybox API, I am using the following code in an iframe:

```
<form>

... // form fields here

<button onclick="parent.$.fancybox.close();">
<span>Save</span>
</button>

</form>
```

The form actually closes when 'Save' is clicked -- but the form content is not submitted. It's like the `close` event is triggered before the form actually submits its content.

Without the `onclick`, content is submitted, but the subsequent page opens inside the iframe -- not what I want.

Is there a way around this?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by creating buttons using multiple `span` (for style purposes) and a few lines of jQuery

```
<span id="save_btn" class="fc-button fc-button-prev fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-corner-right">
        <span class="fc-button-inner">
            <span class="fc-button-content save_button">Save</span>
            <span class="fc-button-effect">
                <span></span>
            </span>
        </span>
</span>

<script>
$('#save_btn').click(function() {
  $('#my_form').submit();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Question here - I'm having the same issue, but how does this close the fancybox? Do you still use `<button onclick="parent.$.fancybox.close();">` somewhere? How does that work?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method like this:

```
<form>

... // form fields here

<button onclick="event.preventDefault(); parent.$.fancybox.close();">
<span>Save</span>
</button>

</form>
```

Then [submit the page using jquery](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

So it will be better to make it in a function like this:

```
function closeME()
{
   event.preventDefault(); 
   parent.$.fancybox.close();
   $('#myForm').submit();
}    
    ... // form fields here

    <button onclick="closeME();">
    <span>Save</span>
    </button>



    </form>
```

```
<form action="" method="post" id="myForm">
    ... // form fields here
    <button onclick="closeME();">
    <span>Save</span>
    </button>
</form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function closeME() {
            event.preventDefault();
            parent.$.fancybox.close();
            $('#myForm').submit();
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it isn't working -- the form closes but is not submitted -- this also happens if i change the line order, with `.submit` before `.close`

Comment: @torr -- I edited me code sample, please try again, hope this work in your case.

Comment: this is mind boggling - still doesn't work - i've tried so many different things, and it never takes the form content when the fancybox is closed - it's `close` prevents `submit` from happening and vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

This one works perfect me:

```
$('body',top.document).removeClass('fancybox-lock');
$('.fancybox-overlay',top.document).css('display','none');
```

All other things didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

for other readers still having trouble getting fancybox to close from an iframe, it may be an issue with iframe being from a different origin as the parent window. that was the issue i was running into. Rob W provided an excellent solution using postMessage here [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fancybox' of undefined - Google Chrome only error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932369/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-fancybox-of-undefined-google-chrome)