# Issues closing iFrame fancybox on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I have an online user roster populated from a database. Each username is a link that opens a form in a fancybox (iframe) to allow editing of info. Without any js in the child window, the form data submits to the database but the fancybox does not close. I need it to submit the data, then close the fancybox.

I've tried Amr's answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491346/close-fancybox-iframe-on-form-submit-using-button-tag-not-working) and it now closes but doesn't submit.

Here's the code that opens the fancybox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $(".updateLink").fancybox({ 
                             'padding'        : 0, 
                             'autoScale'      : false, 
                             'transitionIn'   : 'none', 
                             'transitionOut'  : 'none', 
                             'width'          : 650, 
                             'height'         : 560,
                             'showCloseButton': true,
                             'type':         'iframe' 
                            }); 
});

</script>



<?php
    foreach ($contacts as $contact) {

    $updateLink = '<a class="updateLink" href="update_person.php?people_id='.urlencode($contact->people_id).'&company_id='.urlencode($company_id).'&uid='.urlencode($uid).' ">'.$contact->first_name.' '.$contact->last_name.'</a>';

        print '<tr>';
        print '<td>'.$contact->people_id.'</td>';
            print '<td>'.$updateLink.'</td>';
            print '<td>'.$contact->title.'</td>';
            print '<td>'.$contact->email.'</td>';           
        print '</tr>';
    } # end foreach contact
     ?>
```

Here's what the code of the iframed file looks like now, with the function that closes the fancybox:

```
<?php 

include('/home/www/viola/ssl/include/ez_sql.php');
include('/home/www/lib/common_functions.php');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //write to roster table
    $people_id = $_POST['people_id'];
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

   $db->query("INSERT INTO roster (people_id, first_name, last_name, title, email) values ($people_id, '$first_name', '$last_name', '$title', '$email')");

}

else {

   $people_id = urldecode($_GET['people_id']);
   $uid = urldecode($_GET['uid']);


   $query = "SELECT id AS people_id, first_name, last_name, title, email
FROM new_people 
WHERE active = 1 AND id = $people_id";

   $person = $db->get_row($query);      
   $people_id = $person->people_id;   
   $first_name = $person->first_name;
   $last_name = $person->last_name;
   $email = $person->email;
   $title = $person->title;

?>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?= $jsPath; ?>/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function closeME() {
            event.preventDefault();
            parent.$.fancybox.close();
            $('#myForm').submit();
        }
</script>

<style>
fieldset {margin: 35px;}
label {margin-right: 30px;}

input[type="text"]{
   width:350px;
   /*display:block;*/
}
input[type="button"]{
   width:120px;
   margin-left:35px;
   display:block;
}

select {
   width:350px;
}
</style>

   <form action="update_person.php" method="post" id="myForm">
      <input type="hidden" name="people_id" value="<?= $people_id; ?>"/>
       <fieldset>
            <legend>Update <?= $first_name . " " . $last_name; ?></legend>
            <table>
               <tr>
                  <td><label for="first_name">First Name:</label></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?= $first_name; ?>"/></td>
               </tr>

               <tr>
                  <td><label for="last_name">Last Name:</label></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="last_name"  value="<?= $last_name; ?>"/></td>
               </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td><label for="user_email">Email:</label></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?= $email; ?>"/></td>
               </tr>

               <tr>
                  <td><label for="title">Title:</label></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="title" value="<?= $title; ?>"/></td>
               </tr>


               <tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><!--<input type="submit" id="mysubmit" name="submit" value="Submit changes" />-->
 <button onclick="closeME();">
    <span>Save changes</span>
    </button>

</td></tr>
            </table>

       </fieldset>
   </form>

<?
}
?>
```

Before making the change suggested in the linked post, there was just the commented-out `<input type="submit" id="mysubmit" name="submit" value="Submit changes" />` - this did submit the data correctly.

Any idea what I need to do to get the new code to both close the fancybox AND submit the form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current code is having one of the following issues:

- Fancybox closes, but the form is not correctly submitted
- The form is correctly submitted, but fancybox wont't close.

**Solution**
Working code at JS Fiddle **: http://jsfiddle.net/hMcc8/7/show/** (omit `/show/` to see the source). `/show/` has to be added to get the code work, so that the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) does not interfere.

Include the fancybox JS and CSS files, and define the following function at your main file:

```
function fancyBoxClose(){
    $("#fancybox-frame").load(function(){
        $.fancybox.close();
    });
}
```

**Fiddle for framed file: http://jsfiddle.net/SnTwQ/7/**
Bind a `submit` event handler to your form, which calls `parent.fancyBoxClose()`. The `submit` event is used instead of the button `click`, because it's possible to submit a form by pressing enter from within an input field.

```
$(function(){
    $("#myForm").submit(function(){
        parent.fancyBoxClose();
    });
});
```

**How does it work?**
When the form is submitted, the parent function is called. This function attaches an `onload` event handler to the Fancybox frame. After the form has finished submitting, a new page is loaded.
When the page finishes loading, the `onload` event is triggered. We're calling `$.fancybox.close()` from within this `onload` event. As a result, the fancybox closes as expected.

**Related answer: [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fancybox' of undefined - Google Chrome only error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932369/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-fancybox-of-undefined-google-chrome/7934085#7934085)**

---

**Update: *Another* method. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hMcc8/9/show/**.
According to the comments, the form is submitted to the same page. The following code should always work, when the pages are served at the same domain:

Main:

```
$(function() {
    $(".updateLink").fancybox({
         'padding'        : 0,
         'autoScale'      : false,
         'transitionIn'   : 'none',
         'transitionOut'  : 'none',
         'width'          : 650,
         'height'         : 560,
         'showCloseButton': true,
         'type'           : 'iframe',
         'onClosed': function(){ /* Reset variable when closing*/
             fancyBoxToClose = false;
         }
     });
});
var fancyBoxToClose = false;
function fancyBoxLoaded(){
    if (fancyBoxToClose) {
       fancyBoxToClose = false;// Reset flag
       $.fancybox.close();     // Close fancybox
       return true;            // Callback for frame
    }
}
function fancyBoxClose(){
    fancyBoxToClose = true;    // Activate flag
}
```

Frame:

```
// You don't need fancybox code at this page
$(function(){
    if(parent.fancyBoxLoaded()){ /* Notify that the DOM has finished*/
        // If the parent function returned true, this page is going to be closed.
        $('body').hide();  //Hide body, so that the user cannot submit another form.
    }
    else {
        $("#myForm").submit(function(){
            parent.fancyBoxClose();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I have just added a very detailed answer regarding the same topic. **See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932369/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-fancybox-of-undefined-google-chrome/7934085#7934085**

Comment: Mine doesn't have anything to do with Same Origin; the iFrame contains a page from the same domain as the parent page. But I'll read it more closely and see if it works.

Comment: @EmmyS Can you include a link to the generated HTML (jsfiddle / jsbin / ..). A possibility is that another code block is causing a (syntax) error. As a result, function `closeME` may not have been defined.

Comment: Because this is corporate code, I'll need to do a lot of cleanup on the generated code before I can post it. I'll try to get it posted this afternoon, thanks.

Comment: Well, I tried just replacing the code with what you provided above, and it crashed Chrome (gave me the Aw, Snap page) and didn't submit to the database, either. I'm not sure which code you want to see in jsfiddle - the parent page or the iFrame. I'm not sure there's a way I can connect the two, so here are two separate links: http://jsfiddle.net/EmmyS/hMcc8/1/ is the parent page; http://jsfiddle.net/EmmyS/SnTwQ/ is the page that opens in the fancybox popup.

Comment: @EmmyS Using your real code, I was able to quicly fix it. Have a look at my updated answer. (Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hMcc8/7/show/)

Comment: Well, I thank you for all your efforts, but after copying and pasting your code directly, it still doesn't work. The popup closes, but does not submit. There are no errors, and strangely Firebug shows that it's doing a POST, but nothing is making it to the database. If I remove the code to close the fancybox and just use a regular input type submit instead of a button, it works correctly as far as submission goes, but of course the popup doesn't close.

Comment: @EmmyS I am able to see a full POST transmission.. Another option: If you have control over the page which is loaded after submission, include `<script>parent.$.fancybox.close();</script>`. That should always work.

Comment: As I said, Firebug shows a POST; it just isn't making it into the database, even though the POST transmission shown is the same with the "bad" code as with the no-close-popup submission code that does work.

There IS no "page" that's loaded after submission; the form submits to itself. And that line of code is already there in the submit function.

Comment: @EmmyS Use the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/hMcc8/9/show/. If this doesn't work, you have to check your server-side script, because the JavaScript is handled correctly.

Comment: Well, I know the server-side script is fine because as soon as I go back to a plain input type submit and forget about auto-closing the fancybox, the submission works correctly. I'll give the updated code a try; if that doesn't work, I give up.

Comment: Nope; new code doesn't work either. And as soon as I removed the code and went back to input type=submit, it submits just fine.  I give up. You get the bounty because you've spent so much time on this, but unfortunately it still doesn't do what it's supposed to.

Comment: @EmmyS Check your serverside script. The problem is really caused by your server-side script, because my latest script proposal only executes *after* the new page is loaded.

Comment: Again, I don't know how to be more clear. As soon as I remove the javascript, the submission works correctly. How could there be a problem with the server-side script if it works as soon as I remove the code the auto-close the window?

Comment: Because my newest code closes the fancybox **AFTER** the page after the form submission is **fully** loaded. Have you copy-pasted my whole code, and did you test the right page (use view-source to confirm).

Comment: Yes, I copied your entire code with the exception of the actual button, since you don't have a button in the fiddle. And yes, I'm testing the correct page.

Comment: I *did* include a button in the fiddle. Have a look at this screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Pwp6L.png

Comment: The button is coded the same way I initially had mine. And when I put mine back that way, as I've indicated multiple times, according to Firebug there was a POST, but it does not make it to the database. Making one single, solitary change - not to my server-side script, but to the button (from button to input type=submit) - sends it to the database with no problems. We're obviously never going to agree on this - you will continue to insist that the problem is my server-side code, and I will guarantee you it's not. I gave you the bounty; let's just let it go. I'll find another way.

Comment: @EmmyS Ah well, my last comment: In your question, your PHP code contained `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {`. At your HTML, however, you didn't supply any form element with `name="submit"`, so the if-block, thus database query is never reached. (Also, you're defining `$title = $_POST['title'];`, yet there's no form element called `title`).